# Laravel phpunit emulate keyboard key press

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I am writing tests for the search functionality in my laravel app. I want to mock the user behaviour so in my tests I have sth like

```
public function testSearchCanBeDone()
    {
        $this->visit('/')
             ->type('name', 'query')
             ->press('Search') //In my case press enter key
             ->seePageIs('/search?query=name')
             ->see('Results');
    }
}
```

My problem is at the `->press('Find')` now that I don't have a search button. In my case after typing inside the search field one presses the enter key. How do I go about it. This is the code for my search form

```
<form method="GET" action="/search" role="search">
    <div class="input-field">
        <input name = "query" id="search" type="search" class="search" required>
            <label for="search">
                <i class="material-icons teal-text text-lighten-2">search</i>
            </label>
        <i class="material-icons">close</i>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you crossed that fine line between UI testing and unit testing. One way around that is to call $this->get('/search', $params)